# Can you connect to SAP Query with Python same way you do it with SBOP Analysis for Excel?

Tags: python, excel, business-objects, pyrfc, sap-bw

So currently I use MS Excel to explore and pull some data from a SAP Query I have access using SBOP Analysis tool in Excel.

Now I need to automate this process and what I have done is use a Macro to connect and refresh the data daily, which is good for now but is very prone to errors ie. sometimes the macro fails and I need to refresh it manually.

What I would like to do is perhaps use Python to connect to this SAP Query (It is a cube with dimensions and measures) the same way I do it with SBOP Analysis. Is this even possible?

I have found using the [PyRFC](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC) library could be a solution however I don't think is works for the type of data source I need, or perhaps I haven't found a good example.

Thanks,

Comment: `data from a SAP Query` what do you mean under SAP Query? running queries [from SQ02](https://blogs.sap.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/query_creation_449618.png)?

Comment: Well I call it query because when I am searching for it in SBOP I have to pick "Query" as Data Source type. But maybe I am wrong. To clarify here are the steps I take to connect to my Data Source from Excel:

1) Log in to SAP: https://imgur.com/bs4ZOr1

2) Select Data Source (server where data is): https://imgur.com/n3PcaHK 

3) Select Query as Data Source: https://imgur.com/tMakLBJ

4) Browse data where you can see the Dimensions, Measures, Filters, etc: https://imgur.com/mDqjaMb

Comment: Ok, got it, you mean SAP BO. No, AFAIK Python has no connector for BO and no tooling for analysis as Excel. Maybe the community will correct me, if I am wrong.